# how to get details of a user computer?

Tags: php

I have an image gallery.There is a **report abuse** option for each image.If an image was reported from a logged user,A new record will be added to report_table with user_id,image_id,report_reason and user's IP.

After monitoring few days, I found that some people are logging with different accounts in my website and reporting my images even there is no point of reporting an image.

What i need to do is to identify if the report request is coming from the same computer.As we know most of the internet users works with dynamic IPs.So IP's are not a that much unique data to identify them.

Is there any way i can get more details from a users computer or how can i overcome this problem? Thanks

Comment: in short no, unless you only allow registered users to report

Comment: it certainly is possible to uniquely identify users by collecting various information about their browser and their IP. See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=uniquely+identify+users for some ideas.

Comment: @Dagon Thanks for your quick reply.Is there anyway that I can use a cookie or something to overcome this?

Comment: cookies can be deleted, so no. its about user management

Comment: yes, you should work on user management. Restrictions and limitations should be considered.

Comment: You can try making it PITA for the reporters: put a captcha, and a mandatory message box for inputting why they are reporting the image.

Comment: @goldenparrot oh sorry i forgot to mention that i already have a mandatory message box. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

All you get from the user in PHP is whatever is voluntarily included in the HTTP request, which all shows up in the `$_SERVER` super global. You cannot reach into the user's computer to get more information.

You *can* fingerprint the user's browser more using various tricks in Javascript. It doesn't guarantee uniqueness, but may be a good indicator. This may or may not be a realistic solution in your case. See https://panopticlick.eff.org for more information.

You can obviously set a never-expiring cookie upon a user's first visit with a unique id, but there's no guarantee the user won't remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a lot of infos by php

[PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

or you use

[BrowserHawk](http://www.cyscape.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As for the comments of our stackoverflow guys,The best way to overcome this problem is to use a good and proper user management and restrictions.Even a cookie can do something better,there is no guarantee that cookies will be there in users computer.
So continuous monitoring and user management will do the trick to overcome this.
Thanks for all friends for there valuable ideas.